# SampleGrabber Parameter is Incorrect

Tags: c#, directshow

I'm banging my head over trying to save a jpg file using the samplegrabber in my directshow application. The graph runs fine however when I launch the CaptureImage() function it gets as far as GetCurrentBuffer and returns "parameter is incorrect".. hr = -2147024809.

```
        AMMediaType mediaType = new AMMediaType();
        VideoInfoHeader videoInfo = new VideoInfoHeader();

        (pSampleGrabber as ISampleGrabber).GetConnectedMediaType(mediaType);
        videoInfo = (VideoInfoHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.formatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));

        int width = videoInfo.BmiHeader.Width;
        int height = videoInfo.BmiHeader.Height;
        int size = videoInfo.BmiHeader.ImageSize;

        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(mediaType);

        int hr = 0;
        int bufferSize = 0;
        hr = (pSampleGrabber as ISampleGrabber).GetCurrentBuffer(ref bufferSize, IntPtr.Zero);
        CheckHR(hr, "Could not get buffer size for image capture.");
        IntPtr frameBufferPointer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bufferSize);
        hr = (pSampleGrabber as ISampleGrabber).GetCurrentBuffer(ref bufferSize, frameBufferPointer);
        CheckHR(hr, "Could not get buffer size for image capture.");

        byte[] frameBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        Marshal.Copy(frameBufferPointer, frameBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(frameBufferPointer);

        Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        BitmapData bmpData = frame.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, frame.PixelFormat);

        Marshal.Copy(frameBuffer, 0, bmpData.Scan0, bufferSize);
        frame.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        frame.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

        if (format == "PAL" || format == "NTSC" || format == "NTSC32")
        {
            Bitmap sdBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)sdBitmap);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(frame, 0, 0, width, height);
            g.Dispose();
            frame = sdBitmap;
            sdBitmap.Dispose();
        }

        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)100);
        ImageCodecInfo jpegInfo = null;

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
        {
            if (codec.MimeType.ToLower() == "image/jpeg")
            {
                jpegInfo = codec;
                break;
            }
        }

        EncoderParameters encoderParam = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParam.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        double timeStamp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;

        frame.Save(@"C:\Records\" + timeStamp.ToString() + ".jpg", jpegInfo, encoderParam);
        frame.Dispose();
```

The file does save in the end, if I take out the CheckHR checks however the image is black with the right width and height which is why I went and checked the HR to see if it was healthy. Apparently not. I've searched google trying to figure out the error and any common issues in the matter but again, banging my head. :(

Heres a quick look at my graph:

```
        int hr = 0;

        // Graph builder.
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 pBuilder = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
        hr = pBuilder.SetFiltergraph(pGraph);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't SetFiltergraph.");

        // Add Decklink Video Capture.
        IBaseFilter pDecklinkVideoCapture = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_DecklinkVideoCapture));
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pDecklinkVideoCapture, "Decklink Video Capture");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add Decklink Video Capture to graph.");

        // Get Decklink display format.
        Dictionary<string, AMMediaType> formats = GetDisplayFormat(pDecklinkVideoCapture);
        hr = (DsFindPin.ByName(pDecklinkVideoCapture, "Capture") as IAMStreamConfig).SetFormat(formats[format]);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't set video format on Decklink Video Capture.");

        // Add Intel® Media SDK H.264 Encoder.
        IBaseFilter pIntelMediaSDKH264Encoder = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_IntelMediaSDKH264Encoder));
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pIntelMediaSDKH264Encoder, "Intel® Media SDK H.264 Encoder");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add Intel® Media SDK H.264 Encoder to graph.");

        // Add Intel® Media SDK MP4 Muxer.
        IBaseFilter pIntelMediaSDKMP4Muxer = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_IntelMediaSDKMP4Muxer));
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pIntelMediaSDKMP4Muxer, "Intel® Media SDK MP4 Muxer");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add Intel® Media SDK MP4 Muxer to graph.");

        // Add File writer.
        IBaseFilter pFilewriter = (IBaseFilter)new FileWriter();
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pFilewriter, "File writer");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add File writer to graph");

        // Set destination filename.
        IFileSinkFilter pFilewriter_sink = pFilewriter as IFileSinkFilter;

        if (pFilewriter_sink == null)
        {
            CheckHR(unchecked((int)0x80004002), "Can't get IFileSinkFilter");
        }

        hr = pFilewriter_sink.SetFileName(destination, null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't set filename.");

        // Add Smart Tee.
        IBaseFilter pSmartTee = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pSmartTee, "Smart Tee");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add Smart Tee to graph.");

        // Add AVI Decompressor.
        IBaseFilter pAVIDecompressor2 = (IBaseFilter)new AVIDec();
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pAVIDecompressor2, "AVI Decompressor");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add AVI Decompressor to graph.");

        // Add SampleGrabber.
        pSampleGrabber = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_SampleGrabber));
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pSampleGrabber, "SampleGrabber");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add SampleGrabber to graph.");

        // Set SampleGrabber Media Type.
        AMMediaType pSampleGrabber_pmt = new AMMediaType();
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.majorType = MediaType.Video;
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.subType = new Guid("{43594448-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}");
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatType = FormatType.VideoInfo;
        VideoInfoHeader pSampleGrabber_format = new VideoInfoHeader();
        pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(pSampleGrabber_format));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(pSampleGrabber_format, pSampleGrabber_pmt.formatPtr, false);
        hr = ((ISampleGrabber)pSampleGrabber).SetMediaType(pSampleGrabber_pmt);
        DsUtils.FreeAMMediaType(pSampleGrabber_pmt);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't set media type to sample grabber.");

        // Add Null Renderer.
        IBaseFilter pNullRenderer = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_NullRenderer));
        hr = pGraph.AddFilter(pNullRenderer, "Null Renderer");
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't add Null Renderer to graph.");

        // Connect Decklink Video Capture and Smart Tee.
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pDecklinkVideoCapture, "Capture"), GetPin(pSmartTee, "Input"), null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't connect Decklink Video Capture and Smart Tee.");

        // Connect Smart Tee and AVI Decompressor.
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pSmartTee, "Capture"), GetPin(pAVIDecompressor2, "XForm In"), null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't connect Smart Tee and AVI Decompressor.");

        // Connect AVI Decompressor and Intel® Media SDK H.264 Encoder.
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pAVIDecompressor2, "XForm Out"), GetPin(pIntelMediaSDKH264Encoder, "In"), null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't connect AVI Decompressor and Intel® Media SDK H.264 Encoder.");

        // Connect Intel® Media SDK H.264 Encoder and Intel® Media SDK MP4 Muxer.
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pIntelMediaSDKH264Encoder, "Out"), GetPin(pIntelMediaSDKMP4Muxer, "Input 0"), null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't connect Intel® Media SDK H.264 Encoder and Intel® Media SDK MP4 Muxer.");

        // Connect Intel® Media SDK MP4 Muxer and File writer.
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pIntelMediaSDKMP4Muxer, "Output"), GetPin(pFilewriter, "in"), null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't connect Intel® Media SDK MP4 Muxer and File writer.");

        // Connect Smart Tee and SampleGrabber.
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pSmartTee, "Preview"), GetPin(pSampleGrabber, "Input"), null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't connect Smart Tee and SampleGrabber.");

        // Connect SampleGrabber and Null Renderer.
        hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pSampleGrabber, "Output"), GetPin(pNullRenderer, "In"), null);
        CheckHR(hr, "Can't connect SampleGrabber and Null Renderer.");
```

Any suggestions or ideas are most welcomed. Let me know if more info is required.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-2147024809 converted to hex is 0x80070057 which is E_INVALIDARG.

E_INVALIDARG for GetCurrentBuffer means: Samples are not being buffered. Call ISampleGrabber::SetBufferSamples.

To activate buffering, call ISampleGrabber::SetBufferSamples with a value of TRUE.

Comment: Your right, I forgot to activate the buffer samples. I now get opeation could not be performed because the filter is in the wrong state. Would this error show up if the samplegrabber is not connected properly? What else can cause this error? Thanks Jim.

Comment: Ah, I now have it connecting properly but one last issue, the saved image is black on top of horizon and purple on the bottom? Color spacing issue?

Comment: Color spacing was the issue, all fixed. :)

Comment: @bl4kh4k: i also ran into the same problem of wrong state filter, i dont know how to setup a correct graph for samplegrabber. Can you help me? im very appreciated.